# What exactly does "sudo hostnamectl set-hostname NEW_HOSTNAME" change?

Tags: debian, hostname

Just want to understand exactly what `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname NEW_HOSTNAME` is doing.

Surely it does something other than changing the value inside `/etc/hostname`?